# SQL Get one row of all the dates, and the other rows of today's date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to get the count of row a of all the dates, but I only want the row of b,c,d,e,f, and g to be today's date. How do I do that? Thanks.

```
SELECT count(a) AS a1,b,c,d,e,f,g FROM tableName WHERE date = '15-8-24' EXCEPT a;
```

There are 10 rows of a, and each row contains a different date.
example: 15-8-14,15-8-15,15-8-16, ect;

I need to select all 10 of these rows, as oppose to just selecting the row with the date of 15-8-24.

Comment: b,c,d,e,f, and g are not rows, they are fields.

Comment: Can you give us some structure, and expected output?

Comment: Is there only one row for each date?

Comment: Pretty sure MYSQL does not supprt the EXCEPT clause, and even in those database that do, it does not look like the code you have provided.

Comment: you'll have to run two separate queries. you two conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know that. I was just using it to express what I need it to be.

Comment: @PhilCairns I just provided some examples.

Comment: @Don'tPanic There can be more than one row for each date. I'm just using that as an example.

Comment: You should rewrite your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the count.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName) AS a1,
       b, c, d, e, f, g
FROM tableName 
WHERE date = '15-8-24'
```

Based on your comment, I think this may be what you want:

```
SELECT t1.count AS a1, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f, t2.g
FROM (SELECT ip, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM tableName
      GROUP BY ip) AS t1
JOIN tableName AS t2 ON t1.ip = t2.ip
WHERE t2.date = '15-8-24'
```

Comment: How do I say SELECT COUNT(a) FROM tableName where ip = "The ip of that row"?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, what is "that row"? Could you update the question with some sample data and the output you're trying to get?

Comment: It sounds like you need to do two subqueries: one that gets the count `GROUPED BY ip`, and another that gets the rows with that date, and then join them.